# How to use one scanner for both integers and text?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I need to make a program that allows me to ask the user for a few numbers and keep doing that until the user enters a 'q' but i cant seem the get the hasNextInt to work as i thought it worked. I am very new to Java and doing the ground course atm.

Here is what i have done so far

```
public class Matte 
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {

        int r1 = 0;
        int h1 = 0;
        int r2 = 0;
        int h2 = 0;
        int level = 1;

        String choice = new String();

        Scanner values = new Scanner(System.in);
        values.useDelimiter("\\s");

        if (level == 1)
        {   
            if(!values.hasNextInt())
                r1 = values.nextInt();
            else choice = values.nextLine();
            if(!values.hasNextInt())
                h1 = values.nextInt();
            else choice = values.nextLine();
            if(!values.hasNextInt()) 
                r2 = values.nextInt();
            else choice = values.nextLine();
            if(!values.hasNextInt()) 
                h2 = values.nextInt();
            else choice = values.nextLine();
        }    

    }
}
```

I want to save what ever text is typed in the scanner in the "choice" variable

How do i do it??

Comment: Can you please provide `sample input` and `sample output`?

Comment: Looks weird that you check if the next is int, and if not save to integer??
 How about `String.valueOf(values.nextLine())`

Comment: Why would you call `nextInt()` when `hasNextInt()` is **false**?

Comment: @shmosel my point exactly

Comment: i guess i havent understood exactly what hasNextInt does then.  I want to check if it is an integer and then save it to the variable r1 and if it is not an integer then save it in the string variable.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really understand your problem, but here is a solution for your problem, adding these integers to an ArrayList and stoping the program when the user types 'q'. Hope it helps you. Cheers!

```
public class Matte 
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {

        ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList();
        int level = 1;

        String choice;

        Scanner values = new Scanner(System.in);
        values.useDelimiter("\\s");

        if (level == 1)
        {   
            while(true){
                choice = values.nextLine();
                if(choice.equals("q"))
                    break;
                else
                    numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(choice));
            }
        }    

    }
}
```

Comment: `else { try {  numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(choice)); } catch(Exception e) { /* ignoring input as it was not a number */ } }`

Comment: how do i access the numbers in the arraylist? doesnt work as a normal array.

Comment: in this case its gonna be: "numbers.get(0)" to access the index 0;